# OSX / Unix find command to find Dropbox' conflicted copies

Tags: bash, macos, shell, unix, find

I'm trying to use this command to find all of my conflicted copies, created by Dropbox:

```
find ~/Dropbox/ -path "*(*'s conflicted copy [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]*" -print
```

It does not seem to work though, even when I **am** in the folder with contents that should be a match. e.g.:

```
prefs (George’s MacBook Pro's conflicted copy 2017-02-11).db
prefs (George’s MacBook Pro's conflicted copy 2016-08-03).db
prefs (George’s MacBook Pro's conflicted copy 2016-08-04).db
```

Comment: Use `-name` primary or pipe to `grep`

Comment: `find ~/Dropbox -name "*conflicted copy*"` should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with the `-name` primary:

```
$ find ~/Dropbox/ -name "*(*'s conflicted copy [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]*" | wc -l
      19
```

You can also pipe to `grep` for easier syntax:

```
$ find ~/Dropbox/ | grep -E "\(.*'s conflicted copy \d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}" | wc -l
      19
```

The `-path` primary is only examining the path part -- not the file name. The 'conflicted' file name is a base name and not in the path leading to that name.